# Scroll Listener stops listening after action bar item is clicked in Android app

Tags: java, android, listener

So, in my onCreate method, I have a listener to see if the list is at the bottom. If it is, it updates startLoop and endLoop to add the next 10 list items and calls my FillLocations task to add them to the listview. This is all fine and dandy.

```
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
           if(listView.getLastVisiblePosition() == listView
                            .getAdapter().getCount() - 1) {
                startLoop += 10;
                endLoop += 10;
                FillLocations myList = new FillLocations();
                myList.execute();
           }
        }
    });
```

I have an action bar action ("refresh") which on a click, sets the startLoop and endLoop to 0 and 10 and then recalls my FillLocations task. This works only for the first 10 listings; when I get to the bottom of those 10 listening, it doesn't load any more. This shows me that the scroll listener no longer is listening after I click this action button. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        startLoop = 0;
        endLoop = 10;
        FillLocations myFill = new FillLocations();
        myFill.execute();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```